# When are the auto-generated columns in a gridview added?

Tags: c#, gridview

I'd like to tinker with the auto-generated columns in a gridview a bit.  What event would I want to override to modify them just after they are generated but before the control is rendered?

Comment: note to future readers - I eventually decided that this approach was costing more time than it saved me, turned auto generate columns off, and specified the columns myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link for more information on Customizing the Auto-Generated Columns of a GridView Control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950(VS.95).aspx

The particular event you are looking for would be the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event

[More information on the AutoGeneratingColumn event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(VS.95).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The columns are added to the GridView when the DataBind() method is called

Answer (score 0):

Those two links are for the Datagrid not Gridview.