# GridView Columns are created -generated- when?

Tags: gridview

does anybody know when the columns are generated of a GridView? After what event?

Basically, when I put a breakpoint on RowCreated event handler of my gridview, I can see each time .Rows count is incrremented. But When I check. .Columns.Count property it is zero.

so, even my autoGenerateColumns porperty set to true, why the Columns.Count can be zero. And how a row can be generated while the .Columns collection of my gridview is empty?

Any explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: I have noticed in MSDN a remarkable note :  :)

Note: 
Automatically generated bound column fields are not added to the Columns collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [When are the auto-generated columns in a gridview added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956498/when-are-the-auto-generated-columns-in-a-gridview-added)